# Is there way I can update api url in nuxt?

Tags: api, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a button that updates api url.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    </div>
    <button @click="nextPage">New posts</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      totalPosts: null,
      postsPerPage: 20,
      pageNumber: 1,
      totalPages: null,
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const param = {
      params: {
        _page: this.pageNumber,
        _limit: this.postsPerPage,
      },
    }

    const response = await this.$axios.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      param
    )

    this.totalPosts = response.headers['x-total-count']
    this.posts = response.data.reverse()
    this.totalPages = this.totalPosts / this.posts
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPost() {
      this.$fetch()
    },
    nextPage() {
      this.pageNumber += 1
    },
    previousPage() {
      this.pageNumber -= 1
    },
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
}
</script>
```

In jsonplaceholder, I can set a page number and post limit, like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=1&_limit=20. So I tried to make a button that updates page parameter in that url.

But when I made nextPage method and add this to button, I can see that pageNumber data is going up but not re-calling api using that pageNumber.

Is there way I can re-call api or re-render in nuxt?

Comment: I think if you update your title to 'Is there way I can update api url in nuxt?' it would reflect your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is almost correct, but just minor corrections.

1. Move all your calls to external APIs within the `methods` object in `vue`. Do not define the outside the methods object.
2. Whenever you make a call to a external API mark the method as `async`, as await can only be used within an `async` function.
3. Move all your variables that will be used within the DOM to the `data` method. You had defined the `fetchOnServer` outside of the data function.

Now coming to why your code wasn't working, it's because you haven't called the `fetch` post method on click of the button. You've only incremented the page number. That will not help. Once the page number has been incremented, you need to re-call the `fetch` posts method in order for `nuxtjs` to render the need content reactively.

##### Optimized Solution

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      totalPosts: null,
      postsPerPage: 20,
      pageNumber: 1,
      totalPages: null,
      fetchOnServer: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchPost() {
      const param = {
        params: {
          _page: this.pageNumber,
          _limit: this.postsPerPage,
        },
      }

      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', param);
      this.totalPosts = response.headers['x-total-count'];
      this.posts = response.data.reverse()
      this.totalPages = this.totalPosts / this.posts
    },
    nextPage() {
      this.pageNumber += 1;
      
      // call the fetchPost function when the button is clicked
      this.fetchPost();
    },
    previousPage() {
      this.pageNumber -= 1;
      
      // call the fetchPost function when the button is clicked
      this.fetchPost();
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    </div>
    <button @click="nextPage">New posts</button>
    <button @click="previousPage">Previous posts</button>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your methods nextPost() and previousPost() only update your pageNumber. You need to call your method fetchPost() with the updated parameters. Have a look at this video by Debbie O'Brian on youtube - youtube.com/watch?v=qD1Q3nllYRY&t=148s